# iOS Swift giving error : Garbage at end when serializing data from json

Tags: ios, json, swift

I have the following json to parse. But when the serialization function runs it throws an error

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Garbage at end".

```
{
    "b_categories": [{
        "id": "20",
        "english": "GameCon",
        "translitation": "06af06cc064506a906480646",
        "urdu": "06af06cc064506a906480646",
        "audio": "0863.ogg",
        "file_type": "audio/ogg",
        "file_size": "67.251",
        "file_name": "1462621581.ogg",
        "temp_name": "/tmp/phpisH1mM",
        "listing_a_id": "9",
        "status": "1"
    }, {
        "id": "19",
        "english": "What is your name?",
        "translitation": "06480679 06270632 06cc06480631 064606cc0645061f",
        "urdu": "0622067e06a90627 064606270645 06a906cc0627 06be06d2061f",
        "audio": "0863.ogg",
        "file_type": "audio/ogg",
        "file_size": "67.251",
        "file_name": "1462028674.ogg",
        "temp_name": "/tmp/phpgnGUTo",
        "listing_a_id": "5",
        "status": "1"
    }, {
        "id": "16",
        "english": "Apple",
        "translitation": "062706cc067e0644",
        "urdu": "063306cc0628",
        "audio": "sm1_cln.wav",
        "file_type": "audio/wav",
        "file_size": "108.645",
        "file_name": "1458219047.wav",
        "temp_name": "/tmp/phpzLbtur",
        "listing_a_id": "6",
        "status": "1"
    }]
}
```

**This is my code:**

```
do {

    let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data2!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions()) as! [String: String]

    if let blogs = json["b_categories"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {

        print("here 1")
        let blog = blogs[0]

        if let name = blog["english"] as? String {

            print("here 2")
            let newRecord = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("B_categories", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext) as! B_categories
            newRecord.english = name
            newRecord.file_name = blog["file_name"] as? String
            newRecord.listing_a_id = Int((blog["listing_a_id"] as? String)!)
        }
    }

} catch {
    print("error serializing JSON: \(error)")
}
```

please help

Comment: You're missing the code where you show how data2 is populated with the json

Answer (score 1):

That's not your JSON, or more specifically, that's not what you have in `data2`. I don't know what you **do** have in `data2`, but I tried running that JSON through `JSONObjectWithData` and it works. Your data blob includes something other than what you think it does, and you need to figure out what that is. But you didn't provide any detail on that, so it's a separate question.

You have at least one issue in the code, but not one that would cause the error message you quote:

```
let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data2!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions()) as! [String: String]
```

This will fail, and crash your app. Your JSON is not `[String:String]`, so using `as!` here to force the downcasting will cause a run time error.